# How to figure out who issued a connection request if stack trace starts from ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, android, logcat, threadpoolexecutor

I am seeing a strange request in my logcat where it tries to connect to some strange address - see first line of log below. Seems like wrongly constructed URL by taking company web site and some weird unknown IP. I'm definitely not doing this in my code.

Question is - how to trace the caller? As you can see the stack trace starts from Thread executor.

````
2019-09-14 17:48:51.513 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.513 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.514 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:129)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.514 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:356)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.514 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.514 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.514 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.515 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.515 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.515 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.515 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.515 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.515 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.516 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.516 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.517 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.517 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.517 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.517 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.518 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.518 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.518 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.518 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.518 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.519 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.519 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.519 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.519 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.520 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.520 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-09-14 17:48:51.520 17896-18037/appinventor.ai_google.bimando_control.stream W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)```
````

Comment: What http client are you using?

Comment: okhttp3 (okhttp3)